# Is there an API to retrieve a random video from a public/private YouTube playlist?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, playlist

The question should be self-explanatory. I want to return this in XML/JSON format.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there isn't; but it shouldn't be terribly hard to write a function that will do it from a standard playlist feed. For example, in Python you can do something like this:

```
from lxml import etree
from random import choice
import urllib2

ATOM='{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}'
feed=etree.fromstring(urllib2.urlopen("[feedURL]").read())
entries=feed.findall(ATOM+'entry')
random_vid=choice(entries)
links=random_vid.findall(ATOM+'link')
for link in links:
 if link.get('rel')=='alternate':
  vid_url=link.get('href')

print vid_url
```

Whatever language you're employing ought to be able to do it just as quickly.